# Linear Difference Equation and Method of Least Squares

Tags: linear-systems, least-squares, finite-differences

I'm reading the book "Fault-Diagnosis Systems" by Isermann in the par. 9.2.1a.
The author explains how to estimate the parameter of a linear difference equation using Least Squares.
We start with a standard ordinary linear equation with an error term:

[image]

the equation is called 9.15.
Then,

[image]

The first thing i don't understand is the syntax used by the author. What's the meaning of the | inside $\hat{y}(k|k-1)$ ?

ps: I'm sorry if what i ask is trivial, but when i have a kind of doubt like this, i don't know how to solve it if not asking it in this site...

Comment: Hi: that notation denotes the prediction ( also referred to as estimate ) of $y(k)$ at time $(k-1)$.

Comment: Is the conditional probability ?

Comment: Hi: No. Assume  the model is estimated which means that the coefficients are estimated. Then, that notation denotes the prediction of the next value in the series at time $k$, given that one is at time $k-1$.  Maybe check out a book or a discussion on arima models if this is not clear.

Comment: So it's like the author is saying : "suppose we use a model to predict y. Than we get something like this"  .... :S ?

Comment: yes. but y ONE step ahead. time matters a lot.

Comment: @Jhdoe, Could you please review my question? Please mark it if it answers your question. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

The notation $ \hat{y} \left( k \mid k - 1 \right) $ usually means this is an estimated value of $ y \left( k \right) $ given all the available data up to time index $ k - 1 $.
So generally speaking, this is a prediction of one step in time of the data.

The case above also suggests linear estimation.
Namely, $ \hat{y} \left( k \right) $ is built using linear combination of all the given data.